# When uploading a file into aws s3 with boto3 is it possible to get the s3 object url as a return value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, callback, boto3

I am uploading an image-file into AWS S3 using boto3 library. I noticed that the S3 object url ending does not match with the given Key. Is it possible to get the S3 object url as a return value from boto3 upload_file function?

example:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
file_location = ...
bucket = ...
folder = ...
filename = ...
url = s3.upload_file(
    Filename=file_location,
    Bucket=bucket, 
    Key=f'{folder}/{filename}', 
)
```

I read from [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) that it might be possible with a callback function,  but I could not get it working with boto3.

If not what is the simplest way to get the uploaded object url?

Answer (score 2):

Using the AWS SDK, you can get a URL for an object in an Amazon S3 bucket. I am not sure there is a Python example for this use case however, you can get an idea how to perform this task by looking at the Java example.

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/GetObjectUrl.java

Answer (score 0):

Okey, my problem was that the the filenames I was adding to create the file Key contained a hashtag symbol which has a specific meaning in url. AWS was automatically changing the hashtags into %23, which created a mismatch between Key and URL. Now I changed the naming convention of the file into containing no hashtag, so no more problem occurs.